# How can I remove the previous appended item

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm doing here is appending some HTML as HTML to my `clipboard`.
However, I want to have the option to remove the last appended element/item from my `clipboard`.

How can I achieve this and is the following the most *minimal* and *standardized* way of scripting this?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button:not("#delete")').click(function(e){
      $('#clipboard').append($(this).prev('div.images').html()
                 .replace(/\</ig, '&lt;')
                 .replace(/\>/ig, '&gt;'));
    });

    $('#delete').click(function(e){
        $('#clipboard').html(' ');

    });
    });
```

**I already found an answer to this question but if there is another way of writing this more minimal and cleanly please make any suggestions. thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#delete').click(function(e) {
    $('#clipboard').html(' ');
});
```

Your emptying the entire clipboard.

What you want to do instead is `$("#clipboard").children().last().remove();`

Your also adding HTML to your div using `.append` rather then adding a DOM node.

```
var div = $("<div></div>");
div.append($(this).prev('div.images').html().replace(/\</ig, '&lt;').replace(/\>/ig, '&gt;'))
$('#clipboard').append(div);
```

If you add a DOM node instead then you can delete that. If you want inline elements then replace `var div = $("<div></div>")` with `var span = $("<span></span>")`

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/RpVBK/5/)

Comment: @Raynos I replaced `$('#clipboard').html(' ');` with the following you provided but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @SirB updated. You need to append a DOM node rather then HTML text.

Comment: You sir are a genius! So pretty much I'm saying wrap my elements within a `div` and replace `< >` with html entities and `append` them to my `#clipboard` can you explain the `console` part briefly so I can understand what I'm accomplishing. Thanks @Raynos

Comment: The console is a way to log errors without having to use alerts. Chrome has one built in, and Firefox has Firebug. http://getfirebug.com/logging

Comment: @SirB I forgot I left a `console.log` in that fiddle. It's indeed the error log that you can write to. Generally F12 of Ctrl+Shift+J opens it.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks Removed I removed the `console.log` part thanks guys!

Comment: I have a question. How come when I wrap my `add button` with a container it doesn't append my `HTML` ? http://jsfiddle.net/75KqW/ Can you help me pinpoint what I missed or what I'm doing wrong? @Raynos Thanks.

Comment: @SirB `$(this).prev('div.images')` breaks because there is nothing next to the button. You'll need `$(this).parent().prev('div.images')`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#clipboard').children().last().remove()
```

should do it

Comment: This doesn't do it.. @Peter Lyons

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution of mine:
Hope it will help... someone :D

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/jQyt4/1/)

```
$('#copy').click(function(e) {
   $('.images').clone().appendTo('#clipboard').removeClass('images');
});

$('#delete').live('click', function(e) {
  $('#clipboard').html('');
});
```

**And to remove the 'last item' from the clipboard:**

[**JSFiddle DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/jQyt4/5/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will help someone having this issue in the future. However this removes all items in `clipboard`. I wanted to remove the previous item appended to the `clipboard`.

Comment: @SirB I added that too: see the added demo in my answer! :)